# Camel AggregationStrategy keep excluded message for next aggregation iteration

Tags: java, apache-camel

Hi my input file looks like this

```
AAA,1
AAA,2
AAA,3
BBB,1
CCC,1
CCC,2
DDD,1
DDD,5
DDD,4
EEE,1
```

I want to split and aggregate this to multiple messages but keep associated records together like:

Message 1:

```
AAA,1
AAA,2
AAA,3
BBB,1
CCC,1
CCC,2
```

Message 2:

```
DDD,1
DDD,5
DDD,4
EEE,1
```

And prevent something like this:

Message 1:

```
AAA,1
AAA,2
AAA,3
BBB,1
CCC,1
```

Message 2:

```
CCC,2
DDD,1
DDD,5
DDD,4
EEE,1
```

CCC,2 should be written to Message 1 or CCC,1 should be written to Message 2.

The completionSize is not constant but should be something like a threshold. Regarding the example above working like "Aggregate 5 records in a message if there are further records beginning with CCC put them to the message too."

This is my route:

```
.split().tokenize("\n").streaming()
.aggregate().constant(true)
.aggregationStrategy(new MyAggregationStrategy())
.completionSize(5)
.completionTimeout(5000)
```

After reaching the completionSize threshold of 5, MyAggregationStrategy has to check the next message (newExchange) and decide if it will be aggregated to the oldExchange or not even if the size will be bigger than 5. If  the message will not be aggregated to the oldExchange, the aggregation is complete and a new aggregation begins. How do I ensure that this message that was rejected by the last aggregation will be the first message regarded in the new aggregation?

Since the input file may be very large I will use streaming and not read in the whole file first and then cut it to single messages by a custom bean.

Comment: I wonder if a custom splitter would work better: i.e. instead of splitting by line, read the file and split every N lines... but extending N to ensure that records with the same value in that first field are kept in a single (split) message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not group only the related elements together? You are currently aggregating with `.constant(true)` meaning that there is only a single correlation group to aggregate. Instead, you can do something like:

```
.split().tokenize("\n").streaming()
.process(e -> ...)  //extract the type (AAA, BBB, etc.) into a header called type
.aggregate(header("type"), new MyAggregationStrtegy())
.completionTimeout(5000)
```

This way, only related messages would be a part of your aggregated batch.

Comment: Thanks, the file contains about 50.000 lines. I simplified the attributes  AAA, BBB for stackoverflow. In real life they are alphanumeric Strings of length 6. There may be multiple occurences of the same String or not. The String is a part of a logical id. In the file there may be about 10.000 different kinds of this String. Does the algorithm you suggested create 10.000 type-headers? And then create a message for each type and then aggregates all incoming records to it that have the same 6-character Sting?

Comment: It creates a header with that String for each message and then aggregates the messages that have the same 6-character String into the same aggregation group. So it creates 50k type headers which will result in at least 10k aggregation groups. I say at least because if the records in the file are not sorted, due to the timeout you may not have all the records with the same ID within a single group.

Comment: Ok, understood. But all of this happens in memory, does it? We are migrating an old legacy system. For each line an object with about 50 attributes is created. Holding 50k of These objects in memory could cause memory problems.

Comment: You wouldn't hold all of them in memory, of course - you would hold each group for up to 5 seconds with the current settings, but 5s may be way too much if you're just reading from the file and not doing any per-message processing. In that case 1s or even 500ms should suffice.

Comment: Hi Miloš, it's almost working but now I get a `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: null` but I don't use parallelProcessing?

Comment: This is my process-Method 
`public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    String lt = body.substring(4, 11);
    exchange.getIn().setHeader("LT-ID", lt);`

And this my Aggregation 
`.aggregate(header("LT-ID"), new MyAggregationStrategy()).completionTimeout(3000)

Comment: This only happens in JUnit! If the route runs in a server it works perfectly. Maybe it has something to do with the producerTemplate use in my Unit Test.

Comment: I was just about to tell you that I it works fine for me, but I was running the full app. As for the parallel execution, I think Camel is using worker threads which enable ut to await for completion. My guess is that there's a race-condition somewhere so that your test terminates the executor service but Camel still tries to schedule tasks on it

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on `eagerCheckCompletion` to `true` which will check for completion before aggregation. See more details in the docs: http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2

Comment: Thanks, when I use a self implemented completion predicate and set eagerCheckCompletion to true then in `Predicate#matches` I work on the current exchange. Do I have a chance in `Predicate#matches` to check the prior exchange to check whether the content of the current exchange fits to the content of the prior exchange?

Comment: No that is currently not possible. This would require an enhancement to the aggregator EIP to support such use-case.

Comment: @nick78 in your case, I guess you can keep the last key in your Aggregator/Predicate instance.

Comment: Thanks Darius. I decided using Miloš solution. This works fine for me.